# #ckeditor Drag and drop image from IE11 CKEditor 4.5 Beta

Tags: ckeditor, internet-explorer-11

If i try to drop an image from IE11 to CkEditor 4.5 Beta (just like the sample video) the image is dropped in a new tab of IE and not in the html form of  CKEditor.

It is the basic install of CKEditor. I used the default `config.php/ckeditor.php`. No changes have been made.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in the "Uploading Dropped and Pasted Images sample": http://ckeditor.com/tmp/4.5.0-beta/image-upload.html ?
It would tell if it's an issue with your local setup.

Comment: And what is the question?